# Views don't seem to be working properly on localhost with Chrome

Tags: views

This seems to be something connected to being on localhost rather than a server as once the site is uploaded it works fine - it's almost as if Chrome is too fast for my drupal site. Parts of the views don't register properly (fields will be missing) but some of them do.

The site works fine locally on FireFox, IE and Safari - it's just Chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think your chrome cache is loading the 'old' page

clear your chrome cache:

- when in chrome press shift+ctrl+del
- then check ´Empty the cache´
- click clear browsing data.

should be fixed now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cached data and everything should be fine then.
If not, clear the site cache and the reload the page.
Also try updating the chrome.
Chrome is fast but not fast enough for drupal.